# how to keep my infrequently used programming language skills in shape

Tags: ruby

I use ruby infrequently  - usually it adds up to writing a script once in two  months or more.  I do most of my  programming with C++, which is very different from ruby.

with such wide gaps between my brushes with ruby I keep forgetting  basic aspects of the language (like parsing a text file and other simple stuff).

I would like to do a daily drill of the basic stuff and I was wondering if there is some site I can subscribe to and will send me the Ruby question of the day or something similar.

anyone knows of such a site / Internet  service?

Answer (score 5):

It's not daily, but you might be interested in [Ruby Quiz](http://rubyquiz.strd6.com/).

You might also subscribe to [ruby-talk](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/community/mailing-lists/) and look over the posts there each day.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Jim Weirich's [ruby koans](http://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans). It's a set of ruby scripts organized by topic that guides you through the different parts of the language by unit testing your knowledge.

```
def method_with_block
  result = yield
  result
end

def test_methods_can_take_blocks
  yielded_result = method_with_block { 1 + 2 }
  assert_equal __, yielded_result
end
```

The game is to go through these and fill in the __ blanks. Running `rake` will check your answers.

Answer (score 2):

What about a general problem site like Project Euler( http://projecteuler.net/ ) or the ACM programming competition problem sets ( http://www.inf.bme.hu/contest/tasks/ ) and just restrict yourself to using ruby?

Comment: that's a bit more heavy wight than I had in mind, I was thinking along the lines of  "how do you extract the 23'th line of a file and display the second word"? kind of question :-)

Answer (score 2):

A more arduous (but awesome) task is the google code jam. Just assign yourself one of the problems, and set a time per week to put an hour into it. Quit while you are still working. That way, you hunger for more, and think about it in the interim time.

http://code.google.com/codejam

TL;DR: Find a large task, that is interesting. Work on it in bite-size pieces, leaving yourself hungry for more.